# How do you keep a node in a linked list selected for editing and/or removal?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm making a program that gives you a menu:

```
 1. Show all records. 
 2. Delete the current record 
 3. Change the first name in the current record 
 4. Change the last name in the current record 
 5. Add a new record 
 6. Change the phone number in the current record 
 7. Add a deposit to the current balance in the current record 
 8. Make a withdrawal from the current record if sufficient funds are available. 
 9. Select a record from the record list to become the current record. 
 10. Quit
```

and a command promt:

```
Enter a command from the list above (q to quit):
```

I have 4 Linked Lists:

1. firstName
2. lastName
3. teleNumber
4. accountBalance

I'm sure you can assume what they contain...

Assume I have already added a new record.

I'm trying to figure out how to make a method that would keep a node selected as I make changes or remove it.

```
public void numberNine()
{
    System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
    String fName = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("Enter last name: ");
    String lName = keyboard.next();
    if(firstName.contains(fName))
    {
        if(lastName.contains(lName))
        {
           /*I need to set the current record here.
           I also need to print out the current record.
           That means I need to find the corresponding
           information from the linked lists by checking
           the index of the first or last name because
           both share the same index position for the
           correhlating information of the selected person
           for the current record.*/
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No matching record found.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No matching record found.");
    }
}
```

The only thing is that I'm not completely familiar with the syntax to perform to get the job done, but from what I've come understand after looking around, I might need a method that looks somewhat like this:

```
public void currentRecord(String fName, String lName)
{
    /*check for index of both fName and lName between the two strings containing
      this information until they match up, then select the telenumber and 
      balance that match the index of the fName and lName and print*/
}
```

I've understood the explanations I have found, but there hasn't been any syntax with these explanations to assist me in actually achieving this. Could someone please show me how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void searchRecord(String firstName, String lastName) {
        boolean recordFound = false;
        if(fName.contains(firstName) && lName.contains(lastName)){
            int index = -1; 

            for (String fn : fName) {
                index++;
                if(fn.equals(firstName)){
                    String ln = lName.get(index);
                    if(ln.equals(lastName)){
                        recordFound = true;
                        System.out.println("Record Found");
                        System.out.println("First Name="+ fName.get(index));
                        System.out.println("Last Name="+ lName.get(index));
                        System.out.println("Phone="+ phone.get(index));
                        System.out.println("Balance="+ balance.get(index));
                    }
                }
            }

        } 
        if(!recordFound) {
            System.out.println("No Record found for first name="+ firstName + " and last name="+lastName);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It was educational! However hours later I had already move onto another project doing the same thing in a different way that made more sense. However this form makes individual alteration of strings SOOO much easier than what I ended up doing. I know some poeple who'd be glad to know this! Thank you very much :)